# Converting multi-line string to array

Tags: perl

How do I convert a multiline string to array?

```
my $text= " ads da
sda
s 
da
d
as

das
d a as dasd
\n

";
```

**Note : I dont want to remove or delete newline ?**

Comment: This is a poor question. Define your scope more clearly. What does the string contain? Is that a literal `'\n'`? Do you want to ignore empty lines?

Comment: i dont want to remove new line and empty lines ...

Comment: so what do you want to split on?

Comment: i never said that i want split . I need to convert string to array

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"?  Show what the array you want looks like for your example case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could split on the beginnings of the lines by using the `^` metacharacter and the `m` regexp modifier (letting `^` match the beginning of the line instead of just the beginning of the string):

```
split /^/m, $text
```

Actually, you can leave out the `m` since `split` puts it in for you in this case. From `perldoc -f split`: "A PATTERN of "/^/" is treated as if it were "/^/m", since it isn’t much use otherwise."

Using your value for `$text`, this code:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;
print Data::Dumper->Dump([[split /^/, $text]], ["*text"]);
```

Prints this:

```
@text = (
          " ads da\n",
          "sda\n",
          "s \n",
          "da\n",
          "d\n",
          "as\n",
          "\n",
          "das\n",
          "d a as dasd\n",
          "\n",
          "\n",
          "\n"
        );
```

Answer (score 24):

As it stands, the question could be worded more clearly.

```
my @text = split "\n", $text;
```

Comment: Downvoter(s) : Care to explain what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: this is the best solution for a list of strings with fixed width text fields

Comment: `split "\n"` doesn't catch as many lines as `split /^/` on a string of html content I got via `curl`. I guess it is because the string contains mixed CR and LF characters.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping in mind that the first argument to `split` is a pattern:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use YAML;

my $text = " ads da
sda
s
da
d
as

das
d a as dasd
\n

";

print Dump [ split /(\n)/, $text ];
```

Output:

```
---
- ' ads da'
- "\n"
- sda
- "\n"
- s
- "\n"
- da
- "\n"
- d
- "\n"
- as
- "\n"
- ''
- "\n"
- das
- "\n"
- d a as dasd
- "\n"
- ''
- "\n"
- ''
- "\n"
- ''
- "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

My sense is you are focusing on the wrong problem.

Instead of trying to convert a scalar multi-line string constant into a list, maybe your question should be "How do I have a multi-line string initiated into a Perl list or array?"

Look at Perl's [List value constructors](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) in [Perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

Of particular applicability to your question is how to use a heredoc to initiate an array with a multi-line string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use YAML;

my @text= <<END =~ m/(^.*\n)/mg;
 ads da
sda
s 
da
d
as

das
d a as dasd
\n

END

print Dump \@text;
```

Prints:

```
---
- " ads da\n"
- "sda\n"
- "s \n"
- "da\n"
- "d\n"
- "as\n"
- "\n"
- "das\n"
- "d a as dasd\n"
- "\n"
- "\n"
- "\n"
```

Use the idioms Luke!

Answer (score 1):

I had fun putting this one together: *Voila!* Your string is now an *array* without *`split`-ting* it:

```
use strict qw<subs vars>;
use warnings;

@{" ads da
sda
s 
da
d
as

das
d a as dasd
\n
"} = 1..3
;
```