# How can I split fields and values by = when some values contain =?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting multline string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226042/converting-multline-string-to-array)

```
    my $text = "a=10|b=20|c=20|d=\' I am multing line string  A=10
dfasd fas
d
as df
asd
f a
sd
fas
d fsd \'|e=10"

 foreach my $pairing (split(/\|/,$text)) {
        print "$pairing ";
        my ($field,$value)=split(/=/,$pairing);
         print "**$field,$value**";
        }


its not printing  a= 10 , b=20 , c=20 , and 
d=I am multing line string  A=10 dfasd fas
    d
    as df
    asd
    f a
    sd
    fas
    d fsd , e =10 ?
```

Comment: How is that a multi-line string?

Comment: Also, it works fine after I fix the missing semicolon on the first line and delete the extra `}`.

Comment: i have changed the question . Check it again

Comment: This is just a mildly tweaked re-post of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226042/converting-multline-string-to-array

Comment: Posted code doesn't compile.  But if I add a semicolon to the first line and take off the extra `}`, it does what I expect.

Comment: @zaid - its not repost..

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` and check your code before posting, or no one can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a limit for the second `split`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $text = "a=10|b=20|c=20|d=\' I am multing line string  A=10
dfasd fas
d
as df
asd
f a
sd
fas
d fsd \'|e=10";

foreach my $pairing (split qr{\|}, $text) {
    my ($field, $value) = split /=/, $pairing, 2;
    print "**$field,$value**\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 just for demonstrating psychic powers for WTF this question is about